# Translate animtion multiple imageview from left to right in a way that they appear in sequence

Tags: android

I have three images in linear layout 
i want to animate them from left to right one after the other 
i have made three drawable animations but could not getting them in smooth sequence.

Here is my code.

```
rightanimation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.cloudsanim);
        rightanimation3= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.cloudsanim3);
        rightanimation2= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.cloudsanim2);
        cloud_a_01.startAnimation(rightanimation);
        cloud_a_02.startAnimation(rightanimation2);
        cloud_b_01.startAnimation(rightanimation3);
```

And drawable animation code.

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="25000"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" >
</translate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally animate the views programatically :

```
private void leftToRight (View movableView, int X){
    movableView.animate().
            translationXBy(X).
            setDuration(yourDuration).
            setInterpolator(yourInterpolator).
            setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            //when first animation ends, start the next one
        }
    });
}
```